# How to use Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate with an Oracle Stored Procedure with Cursor Out Parameters

Tags: spring-jdbc, oracle12c

I'm trying to use Springs's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to call an Oracle stored procedure that has two input parameters with set values and the stored procedure returns 8 cursors with multiple columns/rows. I was able to call the stored procedure using Spring's SimpleJdbcCall using the following code (sensitive information has been changed):

```
    SqlParameter con_num =  new SqlParameter("con_num",12); //12 is VARCHAR TYPE
    SqlParameterValue con_num2 = new SqlParameterValue(con_num, "859999"); 
    SqlParameter in_date = new SqlParameter("in_date",12);
    SqlParameterValue in_date2 = new SqlParameterValue(in_date, "20160628"); 
    SqlOutParameter account_cur = new SqlOutParameter("account_cur", -10); //-10 is ORACLE CURSOR TYPE
    SqlOutParameter fund_cur = new SqlOutParameter("fund_cur", -10);
    SqlOutParameter notes_cur = new SqlOutParameter("notes_cur", -10);
    SqlOutParameter withdrawal_cur = new SqlOutParameter("withdrawal_cur", -10);
    SqlOutParameter contract_cur = new SqlOutParameter("contract_cur", -10);
    SqlOutParameter pin_cur = new SqlOutParameter("pin_cur",-10);
    SqlOutParameter alert_cur = new SqlOutParameter("alert_cur", -10);
    SqlOutParameter rider_cur = new SqlOutParameter("rider_cur",-10);   

ColumnMapRowMapper [] columnMapRowMapperArray = new ColumnMapRowMapper[8];

for(int x =0; x<=7; x++)
{
    columnMapRowMapperArray[x] = new ColumnMapRowMapper();  
}

SimpleJdbcCall sp = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
    .withSchemaName("SCHEMA")
    .withCatalogName("CATALOG")
    .withProcedureName("StoredProc1")   
    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
    .returningResultSet("account_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[0])
    .returningResultSet("fund_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[1])
    .returningResultSet("notes_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[2])
    .returningResultSet("withdrawal_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[3])
    .returningResultSet("contract_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[4])
    .returningResultSet("pin_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[5])
    .returningResultSet("alert_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[6])
    .returningResultSet("rider_cur", columnMapRowMapperArray[7])
    .declareParameters(con_num2, in_date2,account_cur,fund_cur,
    notes_cur,withdrawal_cur,contract_cur,
    pin_cur,alert_cur,rider_cur);
```

But I can't figure out how to call it using NamedParamaterJDBC... I keep getting

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17004];
>   Invalid column type;
>   Nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type

```
    String storedProc = "call SCHEMA.CATALOG.STOREDPROC1(:CON_NUM,:IN_DATE,ACCOUNT_CUR=>:ACCOUNT_CUR,FUND_CUR=>:FUND_CUR,NOTES_CUR=>:NOTES_CUR,WITHDRAWAL_CUR=>:WITHDRAWAL_CUR,CONTRACT_CUR=>:CONTRACT_CUR,PIN_CUR=>:PIN_CUR,ALERT_CUR=>:ALERT_CUR,RIDER_CUR=>:RIDER_CUR";        

    ColumnMapRowMapper[] columnMapRowMapperArray = new ColumnMapRowMapper[8];
    for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++) {
        columnMapRowMapperArray[x] = new ColumnMapRowMapper();
    }
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    params.addValue("CON_NUM", "859999",12)
          .addValue("IN_DATE","20160628",12)
          .addValue("ACCOUNT_CUR", columnMapRowMapperArray[0],-10)
          .addValue("FUND_CUR",columnMapRowMapperArray[1],-10)
          .addValue("NOTES_CUR",columnMapRowMapperArray[2],-10 )
          .addValue("WITHDRAWAL_CUR",columnMapRowMapperArray[3],-10)
          .addValue("CONTRACT_CUR",columnMapRowMapperArray[4],-10)
          .addValue("PIN_CUR",columnMapRowMapperArray[5],-10)
          .addValue("ALERT_CUR",columnMapRowMapperArray[6],-10)
          .addValue("RIDER_CUR",columnMapRowMapperArray[7],-10);

    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npt = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    List<Map<String, Object>> result = npt.queryForList(storedProc, params);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!